# For Loop and select by name

Tags: python, for-loop, blender

I want to apply a script to an undefined number of objects. I think :

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
     #do something
```

is the right way. But i need a way to select only objects with the name "Value".xxx and get the number xxx to adjust the 2nd and 3rd line in my script

My actual script:

```
def num_change(scene, depsgraph):
   value_text = bpy.data.objects['Value.001']
   mat = bpy.data.materials['Instrument.001']
   mat = mat.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
   nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
   value = nodes.get("Value")
   value_text.data.body = str(round(value.outputs[0].default_value, 2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to fetch the key, value pairs in your object. You can then use [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20match#re.match) to confirm that the key matches `Value.xxx` and extract the number part, which you can then use to create other keys. For example:

```
import re

for k, value_text in bpy.data.objects.items():
    m = re.match(r'Value\.(\d{3})$', k)
    if m is None:
        continue
    num = m.group(1)
    mat = bpy.data.materials['Instrument.' + num]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a key, you can also access the name of an object using the name attribute. The rest of the code is the same as suggested by [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65086464/15005116)

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    print(obj.name)
```